# Gmail vs Google Inbox. How bad would it be if Google kills Gmail now?

Tags: usability, user-expectation, google, gmail

What's the difference between GMAIL and INBOX and why does google develop both of them? (even due they are both mail agents)

Comment: Can you link to anything suggesting google is even vaguely thinking of killing gmail? That sounds extraordinary, to me.

Comment: Why would anyone have two products to do the same thing? Example- let's say if someone asks me how to do this particular something in gmail... guess what my answer will be? and many more reasons...

Also, searched on Google http://www.computerworld.com/article/2838775/why-google-wants-to-replace-gmail.html
Another- 
http://bgr.com/2014/12/04/inbox-vs-gmail-google-email-app-replacement/

Comment: Both speculative, opinion based articles. I don't think it's worth worrying about. Google caught enough flack the last time they changed the appearance of gmail. Killing it would have a devastating effect on the reputation of google.

Comment: But, getting to the core of your question, InBox is just a front end (app) for Gmail accounts. So I don't see the correlation between InBox and killing gmail. If anything, it's supporting gmail.

Comment: May be you're right and they won't kill Gmail anytime soon but you don't usually divide your resources and users for a single product... Like Inbox is awesome but it's search sucks in comparison to Gmail which could well be because there are two things to focus and as a result you can't optimize both. They would have to keep on testing both the products to improve which would need either more resources or would divide resources.

Comment: Plus, I'm more interested in knowing how would it affect the users and how big of a design change it is and how does one decide whether to change or scrap the plans?

Comment: So you want to speculate on impact of speculative decisions based on a hypothetical speculation? There's never been an email platform provided to the world at the scale and power of gmail. Big things don't tend to be moved much. They become glacial in their progress and change. And gmail is HUGE, besides being the back end connection to Google's docs and many other services. In other words, what you're suggesting (death of gmail) is simply unrealistic, without purpose and lacks an understanding of what gmail is to Google and Alphabet.

Comment: Gmail is not going away, ever, unless it's compromised or collapses. It's the backbone of Google's services and understanding of its users.

Comment: Gmail is big. Fair enough... And yeah, was looking to discuss the same however speculative (or not). Don't have any other platform or anything to discuss it...

Comment: Questions around 'Why does {company X} do {thing}' are not ones that we can answer here without speculating. You need to find product-specific forums to gain correct answers to this. We're here to solve specific UX issues, not speculate on why companies are doing what they're doing.

Answer (score 2):

**Google will not kill GMail, even if they kill GMail and ask users to use Inbox, people will start using Inbox.**

A few factors why people will use Inbox if Google at all kills GMAIL: **Google Search, Android, Youtube**

### Here's why it will not be bad for Google or users:

It hasn't taken too long for non-English people to get a grip on using WhatsApp because it is the best app which doesn't have a better alternative, and even if there is one - because of the **user base** most people choose WhatsApp. 
Generally, **until you have a better alternative you keep learning/using the existing services even though the interface is changed overnight.**

Millions of users stopped using Hotmail and Yahoo after the introduction of  GMail and soon enough in [2012 GMail become the world's largest email service](http://venturebeat.com/2012/06/28/gmail-hotmail-yahoo-email-users/) . People left the old options and chose the one that was better/fast/easy to use.

Since [Google's Android is dominating the smartphone market](http://www.idc.com/prodserv/smartphone-os-market-share.jsp) and the majority of the users have their gmail accounts connected to their Phones and Data (like Contacts, Photos, Videos etc.), even if Google kills GMail people will start using Inbox as it's just a matter of learning a few essentials:

1. How to read received emails and view attachments
2. How compose email with attachments and send
3. How to manage email contacts

Also, there is a **risk factor of loosing data** because it's tough for many to take backup of everything and store it with some another service provider.

**Android's Market Share:**

[image]

In the matter of Gmail or Inbox people will accept the inconvenience as they don't have a better alternative. If at all Google kills GMail which is highly unlikely (because even today we see that '**Loading standard view | Load basic HTML (for slow connections)**' message in GMail) people will start using Inbox.

Here's a little [**History of Email**](http://www.inventorofemail.com/history_of_email.asp):

[image]

Comment: Can you edit and try to conclude it in a line or two? Kinda vague, couldn't really understand all...

Answer (score 0):

INBOX started as an agile project to create a lean mail agent, with time it became a totally different tool with different logic then GMAIL. INBOX logic is that your inbox should always be empty, an it has planty of functionalities that supports that like "snooze" and "done" buttons for example it's also missing some functionalities that gmail has, like attaching large files directly trough google drive: try attaching a 25MB file to a mail and you will get this screen.
[image]. and thats fine, because its not a high priority feture. 
so, in conclution, google has 2 mail agents under it's wings that are intended for different types of users and has different concepts and internal logic. I believe that they will co-exist for many ears in the future and it will be interesting to follow thier changes (especially INBOX).